# Find all functions $f = u + iv$ which are analytic in $C$ and such that $xu(x,y)$ is the real part of an analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Find all functions $f = u + iv$ which are analytic in $C$ and such that $xu(x,y)$ is the real part of an analytic function $f_{2}$. The answer should be given as an expression in the variable $z=x+iy$.

**Comments:** I proceeded as follows: Clearly we need to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations here: $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}$, $\frac{du}{dy}=-\frac{dv}{dx}$ ( *). Since $f_{2}=xu+iv_{2}$ is analytic we can use the CR equations again:  $\frac{d(xu)}{dx}=\frac{dv_{2}}{dy}$, $\frac{d(xu)}{dy}=-\frac{dv_{2}}{dx}$. By using ( *), we get that $\frac{d(xu)}{dx}=u+x\frac{du}{dx} = u + x \frac{dv}{dy} = \frac{dv_{2}}{dy} \iff u = \frac{dv_{2}}{dy} - x \frac{dv}{dy}$. Am I on the wrong track or can someone proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Real (and also imaginary) part of an analytic function is harmonic:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left(xu(x,y)\right) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \left(xu(x,y)\right) = 0.$$

Then
$$x u''_{xx}(x,y) + 2 u'_{x}(x,y) + x u''_{yy}(x,y)  = 0.$$

But $u$ is also harmonic, therefore $u'_{x}(x,y) = 0$, i.e. $u(x,y) = \varphi(y)$. Now use Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thanks. How do we know that $xu(x,y)$ is harmonic? Edit: I found the answer to that question (for analytic $f = u + iv$ then $u$ and $v$ are always harmonic).